# Get the value of a JSON that is equal to a local variable

Tags: json, typescript

I have a function in Typescript that stores a variable that contains a string equal to a property of a local JSON file.

I want to know how I can get the property value with the same name from a local JSON file.

This is my local JSON files:

```
{ 
    "asse": {
        "driveId": "0AcUk9PVA",
        "folderId": "1ouono5dPyhxZPmU",
        "file": {
            "CO": "fileIdCo",
            "ES": "fileIdEs",
            "AR": "fileIdAr",
            "MX": "fileIdMx",
            "fileRange": "Ser, Work"
        }
    }
```

}

This is my current code, but I can't access that property in my JSON:

```
import * as getProperty from '../properties.json'

    function getIdSheet() {

        let country = 'CO'

        let id = getProperty.asse.file.country;

    }
```

This shows me an error that the country property does not exist, I don't know how to use that variable as a JSON property

This is what I want to get:

```
let id = 'fileIdCo';
```

Comment: I'm confused, is it the correct JSON file? There isn't any `country` property there, not even `vtsFile` or `assets` though.

Comment: @Balastrong There is no ``country`` property in the JSON file, what I want is to take the CO property of the JSON file, but passing it the variable that is the one that stores the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct, as there isn't any property named `country` in your JSON.

What you have there, is an object called `file` that has several fields, such as `CO`, `ES` or `AR`.

If you want to access the field `CO` programmatically, you need to pass it as a string. Something like this:

```js
var getProperty = JSON.parse(`{ 
    "asse": {
        "driveId": "0AcUk9PVA",
        "folderId": "1ouono5dPyhxZPmU",
        "file": {
            "CO": "fileIdCo",
            "ES": "fileIdEs",
            "AR": "fileIdAr",
            "MX": "fileIdMx",
            "fileRange": "Ser, Work"
        }
    }
}`);

const country = "CO";

console.log(getProperty.asse.file[country])
```

If you change the value of `country`, you can decide which one to read.